# Twig - Including templates from templates with no context

Tags: twig

I inherited an app that uses Symfony2 with Twig which is a new thing for me, so please feel free to point out the obvious that I'm missing.

Ran into an issue where the same template being included from two different other templates was unable to include a third template depending on which of the two "calling" templates was including it.

In other words,
Two main view templates:

```
smallpictures.html.twig
bigpictures.html.twig
```

both include a third template:

```
picturegrid.html.twig
```

in **picturegrid** template, there is another include for the template:

```
importantstuff.html.twig
```

**importantstuff** template would not properly be loaded depending on whether you were viewing **smallpictures.html.twig** or **bigpictures.html.twig**

The include statement in **smallpictures** was like so:

```
{{ include('MyBundle:SmallPictures:picturegrid.html.twig') }}
```

The include statement in **bigpictures** was like so:

```
{% include 'MyBundle:SmallPictures:picturegrid.html.twig' with {'param1': param1, 'param2': 'param2'} only %}
```

The include statement in **picturegrid** for **importantstuff** was like so:

```
{% include 'partials/components/stuff/importantstuff.html.twig' %}
```

This last included did not work correctly when used from **bigpictures** template - it loaded up blank content on the site.

I don't think the difference in the syntax for the include statement is important here, but according to the [Twig documentation](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/include.html) the keyword `only` removes access to the context for the included template. When I remove this keyword, the **importantstuff** template gets included correctly.

Question - if the template does not have context, how should other templates be included from it? The folder structure looks like this:

```
app
-- Resources
---- MyBundle
------ views
-------- SmallPictures
-------- BigPictures
---- views
------- partials
--------- components
------------ stuff
```

Comment: You should always test the availability of a variable in the temlate. This way you can't get those issues. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44019020/446594) for the available options/work arrounds

Comment: Thanks, DarkBee, but there are no variables used in the include statements. As I understand it, if you don't provide what bundle to use, then Symfony will by default look in app/Resources/views/ , which is where these templates are. What confuses me is why it works when you have the current context, but does not if you don't.

Comment: If you don't use the `only` keyword then the full `_context` is available in each template, included or not. Only marcos have their own scope and can't access the context by default. Does this answer it?